# How to wrap the select text in quotes ("") in Autokey?

Tags: autokey

I use the following script to add apostrophes `'` around text when a specified hotkey is pressed:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection()
keyboard.send_key("<delete>")
keyboard.send_keys("'%s'" % text)
```

Changing the last line to `keyboard.send_keys(""%s"" % text)` doesn't work -- presumably the quotes have to be escaped.

Comment: `keyboard.send_keys("“%s”" % text)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backslash escapes before the quotes that will be wrapped around the selected text:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection()
keyboard.send_keys("\"%s\"" % text)
```